# Multiple Textbox Continuation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, textbox

So I have an idea for a project that I wanna build and it involves uploading a .txt file that will be used to automatically populate x amount of textboxes at 140 characters each (meaning if you upload a .txt file that contains 500 characters, there would be 4 textboxes generated, 3 that are full of text (140 characters each) and 1 that would contain 80 characters (totalling 500).

My issue is that the boxes are used each as their own tweet so no box can be longer than 140 characters as a rule. But I do allow users to edit each box to keep tweets making sense. For example:

Textbox 1: "**Hello, my name is Marc and I am a 21-year-old website developer from the United Kingdom. This text will be used to serve as an example to my**" (exactly 140 characters but doesn't make sense without the following tweet):

Textbox 2: "**question on Stack Overflow.**"

Both tweets rely on eachother to make sense which isn't what the user will want. They would much prefer:

Textbox 1: "**Hello, my name is Marc and I am a 21-year-old website developer from the United Kingdom.**"

Textbox 2:"**This text will be used to serve as an example to my question on Stack Overflow**"

Which you'd agree makes more sense.

But this is at the discretion of the user meaning I can't just format it so that it breaks the file up by sentence.

**My Question Is:**
How do I use jQuery "on key-up" to move the text around in the text areas based on the user. If the user presses the enter key when the caret is inside of the block of text, I want all the text that follows to be pushed in to the textbox below, which would of course in turn push some of the text in that box to the one below and so on.

I hope this makes sense, I have a hard time explaining the concept!

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** here's what I have so far:

```
    $(document).on('keydown', '.box', function(e){
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    var val = $(this).val();
    var box = $(this);
    var elems = $('.box'); //the collection of elements
    if(len > 140 && e.which != 8){
        var sub = val.substring(140, 1000);

        var sub_len = sub.length;

        val = val.slice(0, -sub_len);
        box.val(val);

        if(elems.index(box) + 1 == elems.length){
            // if first
            $('body').append('<textarea class="box"></textarea>');
        }

        var next_ele = $(this).parents("body").find(".box");
        var next = next_ele.filter(":gt(" + next_ele.index(this) + ")").first();

        next.focus();

        next.prepend(sub);
    } else if(len == 0){
        if(e.which == 8){
            // backspace
            //elems.index(box) + ' ' + elems.length 

            if(elems.index(box) != 0){
                var previous = elems.eq(elems.index(box) - 1); 
                previous.focus();

                if(elems.index(box) + 1 == elems.length){
                    // lastbox
                    box.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I actually haven't tried anything so far I'm at a bit of a loss. At the moment I'm just trying to work out the second part; when the user is editing as the initial assignment of the characters can be done easily with explode or substr inside of PHP.

Comment: Update: This (sloppy for now) seems to be working pretty well..

[The code...](https://pasteboard.co/GEKsdCj.png)

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the code (as text, not a picture). It's easier for others to provide help when there's some existing code to look at and work with.

Comment: @avojak thanks for the advice! I'm a long time user of this website, very new to actually asking questions though. I've made the edit.

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately I don't really know enough about the topic to help answer your question, but hopefully now there's a bit more information in your question for someone else to lend a hand.

Comment: @avojak thanks a lot man. Have a great day!